C# Adding exception handling to a method to allow dividing by 0
Here is the code I was given:

class MyMath  //start of class MyMath definition
{
  // Step 2 - Add exception handling to make sure dividing by 0 does not crash the program.
  public static int Divide(int a, int b) 
  {
     return a / b;
  
  }  //end of Divide method
}  //end of class MyMath 


The only lesson we received on exceptions is the small section on W3 schools and that is not exactly helping me right now. I've tried different variations based on other examples I looked up, but I keep getting endless weird errors and don't understand them. Here is what I started off with:
class MyMath  //start of class MyMath definition
{
  // Step 2 - Add exception handling to make sure dividing by 0 does not crash the program.
  try
  {
    public static int Divide(int a, int b) 
    {
     return a / b;
    } //end of Divide method
  }
  catch (DivideByZeroException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }

}  //end of class MyMath 

error CS1519: Invalid token 'try' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.

You cannot use the try...catch in the class body, around the method. It must be used in a method, in this case the Divide-method.

Ohhh, well that's good to know. So I changed the code to this:                          class MyMath  //start of class MyMath definition
{
// Step 2 - Add exception handling to make sure dividing by 0 does not crash the program.
public static int Divide(int a, int b)
{
try
{
return a / b;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
} //end of Divide method      Now I am getting this error: error CS0161: 'MyMath.Divide(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

Yes, you need to return something. So either return something in the catch or behind the try...catch. Since the method wants to return an int you could return for example int.MinValue (better than 0 since that is a valid division result). Another way would be to return int?, then you can return null to indicate that there was an exception. But i don't know if you already are allowed to use int?.

The following may be of interest: Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide) and Exceptions and Exception Handling

Proper exception handling imo should not catch but avoid them. So you should test for zero. This will also be both faster and clearer.

The quick answer
Here's what would solve your compile problem; but this is only half the story...
class MyMath  //start of class MyMath definition
{
    public static int Divide(int a, int b) 
    {
        try
        {
            return a / b;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw; // ***this is important***
        }
        //end of Divide method
    }
}  //end of class MyMath

A better answer
Forget about the exact C# code and Exceptions for now. Forget about the static and the class and so on. Let's simplify the code and think about what's happening.
Your function originally is like this:
int Divide(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}

Now let's call your function from somewhere else. Maybe we have another function that uses your MyMath.Divide() function twice. (ignore that mathematically this is pointless!)
void MyCalculator_Divide_AndDivideAgain()
{
    int startValue = 4;
    int firstResult = MyMath.Divide(startValue, 2);  // this will return 4/2
    int secondResult = MyMath.Divide(firstResult, 2); // this will return 2/2

    Console.WriteLine(secondResult); // This should be 1.
}

This all works fine. Now imagine that we do what you originally wanted, where dividing by zero would be caught and print something to screen. To do this thought experiment, I've rewritten your MyMath.Divide() slightly to make it a bit clearer what's going on:
int Divide(int a, int b) // Let's say that b = 0.
{
    int result;
    try
    {
        result = a / b;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        // Hang on though... what's the value of "result" if there was a divide by zero exception?
        // Answer: it doesn't have a value. It doesn't exist.
    }

    return result; // This is impossible, there's nothing to return. The return value doesn't exist.
}

If we called your code now, passing zero, imagine what would happen:
void MyCalculator_Divide_AndDivideAgain()
{
    int startValue = 4;
    int firstResult = MyMath.Divide(startValue, 0);  // this will catch the Exception, but the return value doesn't exist any more.
    int secondResult = MyMath.Divide(firstResult, 2); // this is now impossible because firstResult never happened.

    Console.WriteLine(secondResult); // This is impossible too.
}

So, if you've caught the exception when calculating firstResult, then what's the actual value of firstResult? The answer is: it can't have a value. It doesn't exist. It wasn't a valid calculation.
In fact the C# compiler won't even let you do this. It knows your code doesn't make sense because there's nothing returned from the divide by zero catching:
int Divide(int a, int b)
{
    try
    {
        return a / b;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        // This causes a compiler error: "not all code paths return a value"
        // You still need to return a value, otherwise the result doesn't exist.
    }
}

Put another way, you're sort of "cheating" by not deciding what to do with the exception. You haven't worked out how to return a value from the function. You're printing it to screen, but that's not the same as doing something. And the compiler knows you're cheating!
The solution is to decide what you want to do with a divide by zero (actually this is true with any exception handling). There are only 2 options:

Decide to return a value.
Decide the program has gone wrong and you can't continue.

In your case, because it's maths and there's a very definite "right and wrong" for maths, you can't return a value if there's divide by zero. Mathematically it wouldn't make sense. So you have to take option 2, which is decide you can't continue. Your code will change to look like this:
int Divide(int a, int b)
{
    try
    {
        return a / b;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        throw; // This is important!
    }
}

The throw is akin to throwing your hands up in the air and saying "I just can't do this calculation". The program will stop.
Lots of people who are starting out programming think this is a bad thing; but actually it's preferable that a program stops immediately when there's an error. Imagine you tried to do some maths on a divide by zero result; horrible things would happen.
So now that you've included throw then our calculator function will do this:
void MyCalculator_Divide_AndDivideAgain()
{
    int startValue = 4;
    int firstResult = MyMath.Divide(startValue, 0);  // this will catch the Exception, but throw, which stops execution.
    int secondResult = MyMath.Divide(firstResult, 2); // the throw means this line never executes, so we are safe.

    Console.WriteLine(secondResult); // this doesn't happen either, so we're still safe.
}

The downside of the throw is that ultimately your whole program will now exit immediately. You might call this a "crash" although really it's by design.
So the final piece in the jigsaw, is that you must somewhere else still decide how to handle the exception - you can never avoid it. In our case, perhaps we do this:
void MyCalculator_Divide_AndDivideAgain()
{
    try
    {
        int startValue = 4;
        int firstResult = MyMath.Divide(startValue, 0);   // this will throw, which skips the next few lines...
        int secondResult = MyMath.Divide(firstResult, 2);

        Console.WriteLine(secondResult);
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException e)
    {
        // ...and here's where we ultimately catch the exception.
        Console.WriteLine("The MyCalculator function isn't valid");
    }
}

Hope that helps!
